# How to prune a data set based on different time slots for different days of the week?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have CSV files for the months of Apr-Sep for the year 2014. Each file contains the following 4 columns like so (I have included two rows as a sample):

```
Date/Time          Lat      Lon       Base

4/1/2014 21:00:03, 40.7531, -74.0039, B02512
4/1/2014 21:00:05, 40.7791, -73.9623, B02512
```

Each file has over 500,000 rows and so I want to prune the dataset.

To prune it, I have decided to use only those rows that fall in the time slots as shown below:

```
Weekdays - 6:00 to 21:00
Friday - 21:00 to 23:59
Saturday - 21:00 to 23:59 and 00:00 to 02:59
Sunday - 00:00 to 02:59
```

I am able to retrieve the day of the week for each row using `Pandas` but I am unable to think about how to go further. I believe that using `if` will be very basic and slow.

My code to retrieve the day of the week for each row in the file for April is shown below:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("../data/apr.csv", header='infer', delimiter=',')
for i in range(len(df['Date/Time'])):
    day = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[i][0]).dayofweek
    print(day)
```

If anyone can suggest a way/library/method that will help me prune my dataset based on the conditions I mentioned, I'd be grateful.

Edit: If you want to look at the actual dataset, you can find it here: [Uber Trip Data 2014](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/uber-tlc-foil-response/tree/master/uber-trip-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the following:

1. First convert he `Date/Time` column to `datetime` type
2. Create a `day` column which indicates the day.
3. Then create our conditions which you stated
4. Use `boolean indexing` to select our wanted rows

```
df = pd.read_csv("../data/apr.csv", header='infer', delimiter=',')

# Convert to datetime
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'])

# Create a day of the week column
df['Day'] = df['Date/Time'].dt.day

weekdays = [0,1,2,3]

# Define conditions
m1 = (df['Day'].isin(weekdays)) & df['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('06:00:00', '21:00:00')
m2 = df['Day'].eq(4) & df['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('21:00:00', '23:59:00')
m3 = df['Day'].eq(5) & (df['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('21:00:00', '23:59:00') | df['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('00:00:00', '02:59:00'))
m4 = df['Day'].eq(6) & df['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('00:00:00', '02:59:00')

df[m1|m2|m3|m4]
```